# pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully with bohrium installation

Tags: linux, pip

I am trying to install [Bohrium](https://bohrium.readthedocs.io/index.html) with `pip install bohrium`, I get the following error.

Collecting bohrium
Using cached bohrium-0.11.0.post60.tar.gz (533 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [49 lines of output]
/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
!!

```
          ********************************************************************************
          Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
          ********************************************************************************
  
  !!
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bohrium_api>=0.11.0 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for bohrium_api>=0.11.0
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 96, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
      subprocess.check_call(cmd)
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/chend/miniconda3/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpwpsz3tbq', '--quiet', 'bohrium_api>=0.11.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  
  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-530j5wul/bohrium_0bf29dd92bbd49629a1a8b891abf33f9/setup.py", line 153, in <module>
      setup(
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 106, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 79, in _install_setup_requires
      _fetch_build_eggs(dist)
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 84, in _fetch_build_eggs
      dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 907, in fetch_build_eggs
      return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
      resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
      dist = self._resolve_dist(
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 865, in _resolve_dist
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1147, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/home/chend/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 98, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
      raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/home/chend/miniconda3/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpwpsz3tbq', '--quiet', 'bohrium_api>=0.11.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  Getting version from version.py
  Getting version from version.py
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Doing `pip install --use-pep517 bohrium` does not resolve the problem.
I have also tried `sudo pip install bohrium` which works and installs it to

```
Requirement already satisfied: bohrium in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (0.11.0.post60)
Requirement already satisfied: bohrium-api>=0.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from bohrium) (0.11.0.post60)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from bohrium) (1.25.1)
```

But there is some error with this method too because `import bohrium` in Python returns that bohrium does not exist. Any idea on how to resolve this?